# What are the best field data types for a table of musical keys

Tags: database-design

I'm fairly new to relational databases. I understand how fields may have `int` or `text` data structures, but when it goes beyond that, I feel a bit out of my element.

I have a table called: `keys`

It is supposed to hold information on which key a classical music composition was written in. An example entry could be: `E minor`.

What I did is create two columns for the `key` table: `name` which is the name of the key, taking on values ranging from A-G, as well as `tonality` which tells us whether the composition was major or minor.

It currently has this form:

[image]

**Question:** What is the best way to construct my `keys` table (in terms of efficiency/scalability) and what data structures should the fields have?

I think it would make sense to have the `tonality` field be a binary. But does binary in this case *need* to be 1's and 0's? Or is there an efficient way to include the whole string `minor` or `major`? I'm not sure if I need to create another table to relate it, or if it can be efficiently done with 1. Also is `text` an appropriate field type for `key.name`? It can only take on 7 values: A, B, C, D, E, F, G. (My data do not include sharps or flats).

Comment: If I understand well then you can have 21 different entries in your table (A-minor, A, and A-major till G-minor, G, G-major)?

Comment: @Marco yes, that's how I initially envisioned it, having every combination of key + tonality. However, maybe it would make more sense to create a new field or table for `tonality`. I'm uploading my latest schema for reference.

Comment: Random question: may I ask what tool you used for the visualization of your schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a 'primarily opinion-based' question.

I would go for a table with the following fields:

- `key_id    integer`
- `key       char(1)`
- `tonality  char(1)`
- `name      varchar2(50)`

The first field is the primary key. The second and third field make up a unique key. For `key` there is `A` to `G` possible. For `tonality` I would use `-` for minor, `+` for major, and 'space' for 'normal'. For both those fields you can make a `check constraint` to prevent wrong values to enter.

Since there are not many rows in this table it be read completely into memory so it will not influence response times that much.

If you do not like the 'extra' primary key then you can also use:

- `key   char(2)`
- `name  varchar2(50)`

The `key` is primary key and holds `A-`, `A`, `A+`, etc.

Comment: Eventually I would like to call `JOIN` on the key table and provide a user friendly way to see the key in full string from, I guess the first approach you suggested would work best for that?

Comment: Not really. Just a matter of what you want. With the first option you can change the value of `key` and `tonality` without 'breaking' the link. For the second one you cannot. Here the 'advantage' is that you can see the value in the rows of your `composition` table without checking the `keys` table. But since the number of rows and size of the rows is very low (21 rows less the 1K) the table will end up in memory (and probably stay there) when you use it so access is very fast.